# Array places string in index[0]

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to javascript. Currently trying to input multiple values from option select into an array and extracting them onto a form.

I've tried both arrays and object methods but results returned the whole string for **x[0]** but undefined for **x[1]** and **x[2]**.

```
// Select Option
Customer: <?php echo "<select name='customer' id='customer' 
onchange='updateValue2(this);'>";

while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { ?>
<option value="'<?php echo $rows['pic']; ?>','<?php  echo 
$rows['contact'];?>','<?php echo $rows['address']; ?>'"><?php echo 
$rows['Name']; ?>
</option>

//Display return value in this textboxes
PIC: <input type="text" id="pic" name="pic">
<br><br>

Contact: <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact">
<br><br>
```

Js Function

```
function updateValue2(e)
{
      var x = [(e.value)];
      if (x.constructor === Array){
      document.getElementById('pic').value = x[0];
     }else{
        document.getElementById('pic').value = Not_Array;
     }
      document.getElementById('contact').value = x[1];
      document.getElementById('address').value = x[2];
 }
```

**X[0]** returns 'Robert','12345678','worths street' 
 **x[1]** and **x[2]** returns undefined

Comment: Really need better code. But `Array.isArray(e)` for a start. Also, on execute `contact` and `address` lines when you know it is an array.

Comment: Your option's value is string, If you want to use it as array, you should replace `[(e.value)]` by `e.value.split(',')`, then you will have an array

Answer (score 0):

The way you are retrieving your selected option in your `select` element is not correct. You have to first get the string from the value attribute and then turn it into an array, for example:

```js
function updateValue2(e)
{
    var selectedOption = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var x = selectedOption.split(',');

    if (x.constructor === Array) {
        document.getElementById('pic').value = x[0];
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pic').value = Not_Array;
    }
    document.getElementById('contact').value = x[1];
    document.getElementById('address').value = x[2];
}
```

```html
Customer:
<select name='customer' id='customer'onchange='updateValue2(this);'>
<option value=",,"></option>
<option value="'pic1','contact1','adress1'">Name1</option>
<option value="'pic2','contact2','adress2'">Name2</option>
<option value="'pic3','contact3','adress3'">Name3</option>
<option value="'pic4','contact4','adress4'">Name4</option>
</select>

<br><br>

PIC: <input type="text" id="pic" name="pic">

<br><br>

Contact: <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact">

<br><br>

Address: <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML rendering is properly?

I don't know it's helpful or not but you should check your loop and rendering process of drop-down, It's confuse when drop-down "select" end and etc...

I have modify the loop, Please look it.

```
  // Select Option
  Customer: <select name='customer' id='customer' onchange='updateValue2(this);'> 

  <?php 
  while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) { 

    echo '<option value=" '.$rows['pic'].','.$rows['contact'].','.$rows['address'].' "> 
    '.$rows['Name'].' </option> ';

   } ?>

   </select>

   //Display return value in this textboxes
   PIC: <input type="text" id="pic" name="pic">
   <br><br>

   Contact: <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact">
   <br><br>
```